# Xampp behind a proxy server. send email via php script using proxy (pac file)

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed xampp on windows and I developed a web application using php, my problem is that I want to send email using php script, there are several script on the internet to doing this, but the problem there is a proxy server, and I use a link to configure proxy in my browser (http : / / xxxxxx . pksyy . com/prx.pac) to connect to the internet.

What is the solution to configure xampp or web server for sending email using php script and using the proxy or automated link of proxy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Comment: my question is different, I have a proxy server and I don't know how configure proxy in xampp.